# In Org-mode, should I use a single top-level headline or multiple?

Tags: org-mode

I'm confused about whether it is better to use a single top-level headline for my .org files or multiple. To put it another way, do I use only one headline with a single asterisk, or several in the same file? I'm running into problems either way, so let me explain so this question can be more objectively answered.

If I use one top-level headline, I can just press tab once or twice to expand all subtrees to the level I want. I really like this.

Unfortunately, when I export to html, my #+TITLE property ends up being the H1 for the page and I end up with a single h2 and loads of h3 and smaller. I'd rather have my top-level headline by my single H1 for the page and not be using so many smaller levels of headings from the start.

Also, are there other gotchas to one approach or the other? Since I've only been using Org-mode a few months, I'd hate to become really dependent on one way or the other only to run into a dead end and have to rework all my .org files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you seem to have missed is `org-shifttab`, bound to <kbd>S-tab</kbd>, expanding the entire file the way you like with one main headline, but which works with many. Hence **you can have many**.

You can do both, really, it's just a matter of taste. I use a few because I see no reason not to use the first level (knowing about <kbd>S-tab</kbd> helps), but I wouldn't mind having everything shifted by one level.

In fact, I suspect changing from one to the other wouldn't even be so hard with regexp replacements, or just manually with `org-shiftmetaright` and `…left`.

Comment: Thanks, I did miss that. Unlike the single top-level I've been doing, S-tab expands to show OVERVIEW -> CONTENTS - SHOW ALL instead of FOLDED -> CHILDREN -> SUBTREE. I think the contents expansion is fine, though I like it even better than subtree since it keeps those :PROPERTIES: cabinets hidden. I'll be happier with #+Title being my H1 while being able to cycle still. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can control the presentation of the heading in org-mode by adding the line (usually from the export template):

```
#+OPTIONS:     H:2 num:t
```

It's worth experimenting with these to get the output the way you need it.

If you want some introductory text, use

```
#+TEXT:        Some descriptive text
```

rather than a heading.